# using Dask to load many CSV files with different columns

Tags: pandas, csv, amazon-s3, dask, dask-distributed

I have many CSV files saved in AWS s3 with the same first set of columns and a lot of optional columns. I don't want to download them one by one and than use `pd.concat` to read it, since this takes a lot of time and has to fit in to the computer memory. Instead, I'm trying to use Dask to load and sum up all of these files, when optional columns should should be treated as zeros.

If all columns where the same I could use:

```py
    import dask.dataframe as dd
    addr = "s3://SOME_BASE_ADDRESS/*.csv"
    df = dd.read_csv(addr)
    df.groupby(["index"]).sum().compute()
```

but it doesn't work with files that don't have same number of columns, since Dask assumes it can use the first columns for all files:

> File ".../lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 155, in set_axis
> 'values have {new} elements'.format(old=old_len, new=new_len))
> ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 64 elements, new values have 62 elements

According to [this thread](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/2053) I can either read all headers in advanced (for example by writing them as I produce and save all of the small CSV's) or use something like this:

```
df = dd.concat([dd.read_csv(f) for f in filelist])
```

I wonder if this solution is actually faster/better than just directly use pandas? In general, I'd like to know what is the best (mainly fastest) way to tackle this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up giving up using `Dask` since it was too slow and used `aws s3 sync` to download the data and `multiprocessing.Pool` to read and concat them:

```
# download:
def sync_outputs(out_path):
    local_dir_path = f"/tmp/outputs/"
    safe_mkdir(os.path.dirname(local_dir_path))
    cmd = f'aws s3 sync {job_output_dir} {local_dir_path} > /tmp/null' # the last part is to avoid prints
    os.system(cmd)
    return local_dir_path

# concat:
def read_csv(path):
    return pd.read_csv(path,index_col=0)

def read_csvs_parallel(local_paths):
    from multiprocessing import Pool
    import os
    with Pool(os.cpu_count()) as p:
        csvs = list(tqdm(p.imap(read_csv, local_paths), desc='reading csvs', total=len(paths)))
    return csvs

# all togeter:
def concat_csvs_parallel(out_path):
    local_paths = sync_outputs(out_path)
    csvs = read_csvs_parallel(local_paths)
    df = pd.concat(csvs)
    return df
```

`aws s3 sync` dowloaded about 1000 files (~1KB each) in about 30 second, and reading than with multiproccesing (8 cores)  took 3 seconds, this was much faster than also downloading the files using `multiprocessing` (almost 2 minutes for 1000 files)

Answer (score 1):

It might be a good idea to use `delayed` to standardize dataframes before converting them to a dask dataframe (whether this is optimal for your use case is difficult to judge).

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask import delayed

list_files = [...] # create a list of files inside s3 bucket
list_cols_to_keep = ['col1', 'col2']

@delayed
def standard_csv(file_path):
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
    df = df[list_cols_to_keep]
    # add any other standardization routines, e.g. dtype conversion
    return df

ddf = dd.from_delayed([standard_csv(f) for f in list_files])
```

Comment: if I understand correctly `dask.dataframe` should already use the `delayed` option.
meaning what you offer is somewhat the same as what I offered: `df = dd.concat([dd.read_csv(f) for f in filelist])` when both should be followed by `df.groupby(["index"]).sum().compute()` to get my final result. am I right?

Comment: I understand this might have not been clear: I want all of the columns in the final df

Comment: In the example, `list_cols_to_keep` could have been all of the available columns, in your desired order.

Comment: but i don't know the list of possible options in advance (there are too many and I want only the existing ones)